# Maximum span in two arrays with equal sum

Tags: algorithm

This is programming puzzle. We have two arrays A and B. Both contains 0's and 1's only.

We have to two indices `i, j` such that

```
 a[i] + a[i+1] + .... a[j] = b[i] + b[i+1] + ... b[j].
```

Also we have to maximize this difference between i and j. Looking for O(n) solution.

I found `O(n^2)` solution but not getting `O(n)`.

Comment: It is written in your book that a `O(n)` solution exists?

Comment: Provide your O(n^2) solution. Its complexity may be reduced by optimizing some steps.

Comment: Yes..but atleast can we get better than O(n^2)?

Comment: @UmNyobe: Create arrays of the sums for the array up to each index, and then iterate for each i,j and check if it qualifies. preprocessing (creating sums) is O(n), and O(n^2) for checking all pairs. Note that each pair can be verified in O(1) using the sums arrays.

Comment: O(n^2) is easy...take all possible contiguous pairs and calculate sum..the indices with maximum sum will be the answer.

Comment: @username_4567 Do you just want an answer or the ability to work from `easy` solutions to more efficient one. Sometimes all it take is to change the data structure used...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an `O(n)` solution.

I use the fact that `sum[i..j] = sum[j] - sum[i - 1]`.

I keep the leftmost position of each found sum.

```
    int convertToPositiveIndex(int index) {
        return index + N;
    } 

    int mostLeft[2 * N + 1];
    memset(mostLeft, -1, sizeof(mostLeft));

    int bestLen = 0, bestStart = -1, bestEnd = -1;

    int sumA = 0, sumB = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sumA += A[i];
        sumB += B[i];

        int diff = sumA - sumB;
        int diffIndex = convertToPositiveIndex(diff);

        if (mostLeft[diffIndex] != -1) {
            //we have found the sequence mostLeft[diffIndex] + 1 ... i
            //now just compare it with the best one found so far 
            int currentLen = i - mostLeft[diffIndex];
            if (currentLen > bestLen) {
                bestLen = currentLen;
                bestStart = mostLeft[diffIndex] + 1;
                bestEnd = i;
            }
        }

        if (mostLeft[diffIndex] == -1) {
            mostLeft[diffIndex] = i;
        }
    }

cout << bestStart << " " << bestEnd << " " << bestLen << endl;
```

P.S. `mostLeft` array is `2 * N + 1`, because of the negatives.

Comment: Can you please complete solution? Where r u printing answer?

Comment: I have completed the solution.

Comment: This answer does not consider the condition where the sequence starts in the first array element.  The code block setting `bestStart` will not be entered unless `mostLeft[diffIndex] != 1`, but then `bestStart` is assigned `mostLeft[diffIndex] + 1`.  This makes 0 an impossible value for `bestStart`.

Take the two arrays {1},{1} as an example input to show this problem.

Comment: Identical solution is posted here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-span-sum-two-binary-arrays/. Don't know which was first ;)

Answer (score 7):

Best solution is *O(n)*

First let `c[i] = a[i] - b[i]`, then question become find *i*, *j*, which `sum(c[i], c[i+1], ..., c[j]) = 0`, and max `j - i`.

Second let `d[0] = 0`, `d[i + 1] = d[i] + c[i], i >= 0`, then question become find *i*, *j*, which `d[j + 1] == d[i]`, and max `j - i`.

The value of `d` is in range `[-n, n]`, so we can use following code to find the answer

```
answer = 0, answer_i = 0, answer_j = 0
sumHash[2n + 1] set to -1
for (x <- 0 to n) {
  if (sumHash[d[x]] == -1) {
    sumHash[d[x]] = x
  } else {
    y = sumHash[d[x]]
    // find one answer (y, x), compare to current best
    if (x - y > answer) {
      answer = x - y
      answer_i = y
      answer_j = y
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation. I was struggling too much to understand the concept of the solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, my solution goes like this.

Take a variable to take care of the difference since the beginning.

```
int current = 0;
for index from 0 to length
    if a[i] == 0 && b[i] == 1
        current--;
    else if a[i] == 1 && b[i] == 0
        current++;
    else
        // nothing;
```

Find the positions where the variable has the same value, which indicates that there are equal 1s and 0s in between.

---

Pseudo Code:

Here is my primary solution:

```
int length = min (a.length, b.length);
int start[] = {-1 ... -1}; // from -length to length
start[0] = -1;
int count[] = {0 ... 0};   // from -length to length
int current = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (a[i] == 0 && b[i] == 1)
        current--;
    else if (a[i] == 1 && b[i] == 0)
        current++;
    else
        ; // nothing

    if (start[current] == -1) // index can go negative here, take care
        start[current] = current;
    else
        count[current] = i - start[current];
}
return max_in(count[]);
```

Comment: Nice, the 'current' counter simplifies things. I was thinking of cumulative frequency at first when i wrote mine, although our solutions would be exactly the same otherwise

Answer (score 4):

This is a fairly straightforward O(N) solution:

let `sa = [s1, s2, s3.. sn]` where `si = sum(a[0:i])` and similar for `sb`

then `sum(a[i:j]) = sa[j]-sa[i]`
and `sum(b[i:j]) = sb[j] - sb[i]`

Note that because the sums only increase by 1 each time, we know `0 <= sb[N], sa[N] <=N`

`difference_array = [d1, d2, .. dn]` where `di = sb[i] - sa[i] <= N`

note if `di = dj`, then `sb[i] - sa[i] = sb[j] - sa[j]` which means they have the same sum (rearrange to get `sum(b[i:j]) and sum(a[i:j])` from above).

Now for each difference we need its **max position occurrence and min position occurrence**

Now for each difference di, the difference between max - min, is an i-j section of equal sum. Find the maximum max-min value and you're done.

sample code that should work:

```
a = []
b = []
sa = [0]
sb = [0]
for i in a:
    sa.append(sa[-1] + i)
for i in b:
    sb.append(sb[-1] + i)

diff = [sai-sbi for sai, sbi in zip(sa, sb)]
min_diff_pos = {}
max_diff_pos = {}
for pos, d in enumerate(diff):
    if d in min_diff_pos:
        max_diff_pos[d] = pos
    else:
        min_diff_pos[d] = pos

ans = min(max_diff_pos[d] - min_diff_pos[d] for d in diff)
```